# Best way to break a 'while/try' loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

What is the most efficient, fastest, pythonic way to endup a while loop?

```
While (1):
    try:
        os.remove(fileA)         
    except:       
        continue
    break
```

Or:

```
While (fileA):
    try:
        os.remove(fileA)         
    except:       
        continue
    break
```

Is while(true) a better option than while(1)?

Comment: check with statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is covered explicitly in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) but it's a good reference for questions like this.  Without more context, the more Pythonic way is to use `while True` as opposed to `while (1)` but it would be perfectly acceptable to also use `while fileA`, depending on what `fileA` contains.

Since you're using Python, you should use snake_case instead of camelCase for variable names (so `file_a` not `fileA`).

Going back to your example, if fileA were a list of file names, the following would be Pythonic:

```
file_a = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
while file_a:
    try:
        os.remove(file_a.pop())
    except:
        continue
```

From your example, it's not clear to me why you use a loop or `break` statement.  Posting more details will help others answer your question.

Comment: OP's code will try removing a file (and keep trying indefinitely if removal fails) whereas your code will only try removing each file once. `while fileA` would be unpythonic IMO - `fileA` wouldn't change even if the file was removed, and if it *is*  removed, `break` leaves the loop anyway...